# Changing from Activities to Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

I am trying to fix up my app code and transition from Activities to Fragments, in order to transition to the navigation draw and eventually have some sliding tabs too.

Currently for navigation I am using the 3 dots drop down menu from the action bar which I know is not really right. Which is why I am trying to transition to fragments.

I want to keep my action bar menu so I can keep my search icon in the action bar but I want to add a navigation draw to it.

I currentley have a class called ActionBarMenu which extends activity. All my activities come form this because this class holds all the functions which open new activities for the action bar menu I have set up right now.

```
public class ActionbarMenu extends Activity {

    public void goToSearch (MenuItem item) {
        // go to search page
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Search.class);
        startActivity(i); 
    }

    public void goToStatistics (MenuItem item) {
        // go to search page
        Intent i = new Intent(this,StatisticsPage.class);
        startActivity(i); 
    }

    public void goToFindBrewery (MenuItem item) {
        // go to search page
        Intent i = new Intent(this,FindBrewery.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void goToContact (MenuItem item) {
        // go to search page
        Intent i = new Intent(this,ContactPage.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void goToPortfolio (MenuItem item) {
        // go to search page
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Portfolio.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void goToDiscover (MenuItem item) {
        // go to search page
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Discover.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void scanBarcode (MenuItem item) {
        //open scanner
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
    }

    //get result value
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        // retrieve scan result
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            // we have a result
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            // launch async task for results
            String url = "http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/search/upc?code=" + scanContent + "&key=0cdb22f84315834cc807c0176a927060&format=json&withBreweries=y";

            new GetBeerDataFromUPCJSON(this).execute(url);
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change it to a fragment by changing extends activity to extends Fragment and all intents I build to launch new activities all get the red squiggly underline. I am just experimenting and trying to learn what's going on and whats the best way to transition my app from activities to Fragments, without having to recode everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is probably because in a line such as

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Discover.class);
```

`this` now refers to a `Fragment` instead of an `Activity`. `Intent()` expects a `Context` as the first argument; `Activity` extends `Context`, but `Fragment` does not. To fix your problem, you should change `this` to `getActivity()`.

For future reference, mousing over the little red x that appears next to the error should tell you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using intents, you'll use the fragment manager to load new fragments. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) page on the android website about fragments.

Comment: SO I will need to change all those activities into frgaments then I inflate the different fragments. 

But I guess I will get rid of these eventually since I will use a navigation drawer instead. I am just trying to understand how all these things work now I guess.

Comment: Yes, you'll probably have one main activity which hosts all the fragments. Implement the navigation drawer in the activity. It might be easier to start a new project than to modify your current one.

Comment: If i start a new project in android studio I need to keep the package name the same if I want to upload it to the play store, correct?

Comment: yes, that's correct, but you can refactor the package name at any time if you need it to be different in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

The finished code for quick replacement would be:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Discover.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to make it same like backpressed if the activity is just next from your fragment like... it should work ....

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

     onBackPressed();

        }
```